# What means Port number usb-device command?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, c, c++

I going to write program with C++ for USB device and i going to display Port Number,when you type in your terminal `root@raminfp# usb-device` you will see in output :

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 7
```

what means `Port:00` or `Port:01` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/proc_usb_info.txt

```
T:  Bus=dd Lev=dd Prnt=dd Port=dd Cnt=dd Dev#=ddd Spd=dddd MxCh=dd
118 |   |      |      |       |       |      |        |        |__MaxChildren
119 |   |      |      |       |       |      |        |__Device Speed in Mbps
120 |   |      |      |       |       |      |__DeviceNumber
121 |   |      |      |       |       |__Count of devices at this level
122 |   |      |      |       |__Connector/Port on Parent for this device
123 |   |      |      |__Parent DeviceNumber
124 |   |      |__Level in topology for this bus
125 |   |__Bus number
126 |__Topology info tag
```